# Turn Off Clicking Keyboard Sound programmatically (iOS)

Tags: ios, keyboard, audio

Is there any way to disable the sound when the user is typing on the keyboard.

Comment: no - not possible from code..

Comment: Why would you want to put this in an app when it's a user-preference setting for the iOS device itself? Emphasis on user-preference. I'm genuinely curious as to your reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you are using the official iOS SDK. It may be possible using private frameworks, but your app would not be approved for sale on the iTunes App Store if you used them.